# vim mapping (vnormap), how to use

Tags: javascript, vim, vim-plugin

I am brand new to VIM and wanted to use vim-jsbeautify https://github.com/maksimr/vim-jsbeautify. It calls for adding the following lines into the .vimrc file.

```
autocmd FileType javascript vnoremap <buffer>  <c-f> :call RangeJsBeautify()<cr>
autocmd FileType html vnoremap <buffer> <c-f> :call RangeHtmlBeautify()<cr>
autocmd FileType css vnoremap <buffer> <c-f> :call RangeCSSBeautify()<cr>
```

I looked at other map examples and they seem simple. But I'm not sure how multi-key mapping works. I am looking a simple explanation of what steps I need to take the beautify function. Do I need to use ":" in visual mode, am I using c-f or cr, is the "-" required, etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`:` will let you enter the command in command mode. and `call Foo()` is a vim command, it calls a function named `Foo()`, without mapping, you could press `:call Foo()<Enter>` to do the function call.

`<c-f>` means `Ctrl-F`

The mappings let you in visualmode press ctrl-F to call the corresponding function, depends on the file (filetype) you opened. if you are not satisfied with them you can change the `<c-f>` to other key combinations you like.

If this doesn't answer your question, just make your question more clear, like "I want to press X key to do Y (or call Y function)"

Comment: so if i would want to map this with a string ex: "JsBeautify", such that i execute the call when i use `:JsBeautify` should the script be - `map JsBeautfy :call JsBeautify()<cr>`